# After adding Layouts programmatically how can I change the "#" text view by button click

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

**The goal is to increment and decrement the # symbol on button click**

[image: Two layouts in scroll view programmatically added]

So the above picture is the inner of a scroll view. I add the layouts to the scrollview with the following code. What I can't seem t

```
 if(json.string("status")=="Success"){

                            var ticketAr:JsonArray<JsonObject>? = json.array("info")


                            for(i in ticketAr?.indices!!){
                                Log.d("indicies",i.toString())
                                val inf1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ticket_individual,null,false)
                                inf1.setId(parseInt(ticketAr[i].string("ntb_id")))
                                inf1.tck_cat_title.text = ticketAr[i].string("age_group_desc")
                                inf1.tck_cost.text = "$"+ticketAr[i].string("amount")
                                inf1.plus_button.setOnClickListener {
                                    Log.d("plusplus",parent.parent.toString())

                                }
                                inf1.minus_button.setOnClickListener {
                                    Log.d("minusminus",parent.toString())

                                }
                                ticket_holder.addView(inf1)
                            }
                            getData("available",event)
                        }
```

Comment: inf1.plus_button.setOnClickListener {
                                  inf1.hash.text="1"

                                }
Will above one work for you ?

Comment: ok what does that exactly do?

Comment: on plus_button click it will set textview with id "hash" with test "1"

Comment: yes but both areas will have the same ID because they are being generated from the loop inflator. I'm working around things by using tags...which I will document here when I'm done with the way of doing it.

Comment: Even if it having same id, both will be in different view since you are inflating view programmatically